# Unable to start Bluemix MobileFirst services starter app

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, ibm-mobile-services

I have created a MobileFirst starter app on the Bluemix platform. I am using the default code generated on an app creation. On app start, `cf logs <appname>` shows

> ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections

Is there any issue with the US-South region? 
What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are not aware of any ongoing issue in US South as you can see on the [Bluemix Status Page](https://status.ng.bluemix.net). I've just tried to create a new application using the [MobileFirst Services Starter](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/starters/mobilefirst-services-starter/) (leaving all the default settings): I'm able to see the example "HelloTodo" page and there are no errors in the logs. I used both the [Classic UI](https://console.ng.bluemix.net) and the ["New Experience" UI](https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net). I suggest you to try again, it should work.

Comment: i will try to delete the existing app and create a new app.

Comment: yeah its working..
not sure why the older app stopped working though. I didn't change any code, it was all default code. only thing i changed was the hello world Android code for Route and GUID.